# automate input values in yii at model

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to automate the input values of

```
'Created By', 'Created On','Modified By','Modified On'
```

I am doing like this in rules

```
array('modified','default',
              'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
              'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
        array('created,modified','default',
              'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
              'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
```

and unable to make them work

Comment: This should work, if it doesn't there's some problem with how things are being done.

Comment: there is some error? or operation success, but fields empty?

Comment: these fields need to be there in ui?  i have removed them from ui @Jon

Comment: What does it means? There is a error that fields are required?

Comment: @alex yes there is error those fields are required

Answer (score 0):

Remove rule where this fields are required. It says that user must fill them.